# Sistema de Transmissão pela rede

Tags: javascript

Olá, alguém pode me dar um norte de como funciona a transmissão na rede tal como o spotify que no seu web player aparece um botão de transmissão, que quando se clica ele aparece a minha SMART TV e ao clicar nela automaticamente a musica passa para la, é possível fazer este sistema com js?

Comment: Olá! Vê se este link ajuda:
[Programando para Chromecast](https://www.tiagogouvea.com.br/programando-para-chromecast)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pergunta é muito ampla, mas dá para deixar alguns conceitos e práticas básicas. A maioria desses aplicativos estão conectados a plataformas ou APIs que estão na nuvem e o que você vê na tela do seu celular ou na TV, são apenas clientes que se comunicam com a mesma API no servidor ou com APIs que se comunicam entre si.

Na maioria das vezes você não está transmitindo conteúdo de um dispositivo para o outro, mas sim enviando a informação para um serviço de que deseja assistir determinado conteúdo em um dispositivo específico. Como essa plataforma sabe onde você está com o aplicativo aberto ela consegue enviar o comando para iniciar a reprodução no dispositivo selecionado.

Mas também é possível, de fato, realizar um broadcast de um dispositivo para outro através de protocolos como o [DLNA](https://www.dlna.org/) que é suportando por muitos aparelhos de TV, Celulares, Tablets e etc. (praticamente, se é um dispositivo de produção de mídia e se conecta a uma rede via ethernet, provalvente suporta `DLNA`. Existem várias bibliotecas que implementam ou tentam implementar a API desse protocolo. ([exemplos](https://libraries.io/search?keywords=dlna&languages=JavaScript))

Inclusive existem várias outras formas de abordar a questão, como por exemplo através do [Kodi](https://kodi.tv/), que é o sucessor do `XMBC`.